# Use function from other C file by a function pointer

Tags: c, static, function-pointers, function-definition, linkage

First of all, I'm not sure if the title describes well the problem, feel free to change or suggest a more fitting heading.

I have the following problem:
I need to pass a function pointer to some struct. When I define the function in the same file, this works perfectly fine. See here:

```
static void a_func(int param1, /*...*/) {
    //...
}

static const struct bt_mesh_handlers my_handlers = {
    .set = a_func,
    // ...
};
```

---

When I now define this function in another file, I can't get it to work:
the header file (include guards are not shown here):

```
//function declaration:
void a_func(int param1, /*...*/);
```

the c file:

```
//function definition (this was defined wrongly as static before)
void a_func(int param1, /*...*/) {
    //...
}
```

in the main-file:

```
#include "myheader.h"

static const struct bt_mesh_handlers my_handlers = {
    .set = a_func,
    // ...
};
```

When I outsource my function to another file, I get the following error during build:

undefined reference to `a_func'

I already did some research and I'm relatively sure that in the file where a_func is defined, there automatically is generated a function pointer with the same name. Consequently, I can use that pointer to hand over my function to the struct.

But I don't know how to get that function pointer from the outsourced file into my main file.
What would a good solution look like?

Comment: Thanks for your tips, you are absolutely right. I fixed this in my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `static` from the declarations of `a_func`, including its definition.

In this context, `static` gives the identifier `a_func` *internal linkage*, meaning uses of the name will only be linked to a definition of the name in the same translation unit (the source file being compiled, including all files it includes directly or indirectly).

To link to a name defined in another translation unit, you want *external linkage*. That is the default for functions, so removing `static` will give you external linkage.

> I already did some research and I'm relatively sure that in the file where a_func is defined, there automatically is generated a function pointer with the same name.

The name of a function refers to the function. It designates the function. In C, a function designator is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`. There is no special or separate “generation” of a function pointer with the same name as the function in the file where it is defined. The compiler, linker, and/or program loader work together to know where the function is and to generate appropriate instructions to use the function or to provide its address.

Comment: As already stated in my other questions, I put the static here by mistake (when I tested I didn't use it). Unfortunately, it is still not building.
Thanks a lot for the great explanation of the designator being converted to a pointer, that already explained a lot. But as I assume now, this designator/pointer only seems to be seen in the file itself, not by files that include the header file. 
So is there a way to make it visible for outer files as well? Or where else could be the issue? My file is still not building, I get the same error :/

Comment: @Sespaetzlean: Show the exact error message and the command used to link the program.

Comment: I'm building with nRF Connect. The command should be sth like: west build ... . (I just hit the build button in VS code in the nRF connect extension)
I get the following error:
d:/ncs/toolchains/v2.3.0/opt/zephyr-sdk/arm-zephyr-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-zephyr-eabi/12.1.0/../../../../arm-zephyr-eabi/bin/ld.exe: app/libapp.a(model_handler.c.obj):(.rodata.lvl_handlers+0x0): undefined reference to `a_func'

Comment: You will need to dig the actual link command out of the build log or figure out what in your build settings is wrong. A likely cause is that your project is not linking all the object modules together into one program.

Comment: I did some research and my files have not been linked properly.
Thx for the help, I thought it was a visibility issue :)

Answer (score 1):

A static function shall be defined in each translation unit where it is used because it has internal linkage. So in the translation unit with `main` in your example the function is not defined,

Either define it in the header (you can define it for example as an inline function) or remove the storage class specifier `static` to make the function with external linkage.

Comment: Not an answer for the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right, I put the static keyword by mistake here in my question (and now fixed in the question :) )

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up: The issue was that my files had not been linked properly.
It is possible to call a function from a different file AND to use its pointer
(that did not work for me in the beginning).
Eric explained well how this works via a designator.